# Multiple time units in one time series graph in Grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I have two metrics which i want to show on the time series panel:

```
histogram_quantile(
    0.95, 
    rate(correction_ms_bucket[1m])
)


histogram_quantile(
    0.95, 
    rate(request_time_bucket[1m])
)
```

The problem is that my panel has unit `Time/milliseconds` but the `request_time_bucket` metric is seconds (i can't change the metric itself since it is legacy metric and something depends on it's format already).

Is there any way to cast it or perhaps to control units for each query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, seconds can be simply multiplied to milliseconds:

```
histogram_quantile(
    0.95, 
    rate(request_time_bucket[1m])
) * 1000
```

And no other change is required.

In other cases (when dealing with completely different units) it is possible to create "overrides" for default values:

[image: example]

In the example above "latency" time series has a different axis (so that it appears on the right side of the panel) and unit (milliseconds).

Comment: It worked but it creates another ruler at the right side with different scale which is ruins the purpose: now the red line has the same size as the green one but it's values actually twice as smaller: https://ibb.co/wJQSGbT

Comment: @DenisNovac try to set the axis (left or hidden) along with the unit.

Comment: it helps when i set the right axis max to the same value as the left. But if left maximum changes - i'll need to change the right axis manually. Is there a way to make it the same as the other axis automatically?

Comment: @DenisNovac I know no way to do that.

Comment: @DenisNovac omg, I'm so stupid. You can multiply seconds to milliseconds and there is no need for overrides.

Comment: i didn't knew you can multiply `rate()` results, thanks!

Comment: well... it seems that you can't multiply it. I tried to add *1000 after rate() query but the graph and it's values didn't changed

Comment: @DenisNovac weird. It should work with any instant vector but apparently it doesn't. Sorry for this confusion, move the multiplication to the end: `histogram_quantile(...) * 1000`.   It should be more efficient this way in either case.

Comment: @DenisNovac and just for the sake of clarity, you can multiply `rate()` result but somehow it does not work inside `histogram_quantile()` function.